# Trying to Implement Python-Style len() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, call, bind, apply

I've been reading a lot about `call()` and `bind()` in JavaScript, specifically the **Creating Shorcuts** section on this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

I'm trying to implement the following Python-esque function in JS:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
len(arr); // 3
```

I do realize this is a contrived example, but I'm trying to wrap my head around these methods. Here's how I implemented it:

```
var len = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.slice.length );
len([1,2,3]);
```

When I run it, I get:

```
len([1,2,344])
^

TypeError: len is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/j6/3fs5_k3n17z_0j2xrwj6sphw0000gn/T/CodeRunner/Untitled 11.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

What am I missing here to understand how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're setting the variable `len`, in your code, you're actually setting `len` to a copy of the function `Function.prototype.call`, with a `this` (context) of `Array.prototype.slice.length`.

I think you're misunderstanding the use of bind(). Say I have a function `len`:

```
var len = function() {
    return this.length;
};
```

And you wanted to get the length of an array:

```
len.call([1,2,3]);
```

In this case, `this` in `len` is the array `[1,2,3]`, because we used `call` to supply `this`. Say we want to permanently bind that array to that function and store it in a variable we can use anytime:

```
var myArrayLen = len.bind([1,2,3]);
```

Now, myArrayLen is basically a copy of len, permanently bound with a `this` of `[1,2,3]`. If we call it, it returns 3.

In your example, `Array.prototype.slice.length` is actually the length of the function `Array.prototype.slice`, which corresponds to the [number of arguments that can be passed to the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

There is no built in length() function, so to follow your (admittedly) contrived example, we just need to make a function that provides the length, add it to the array prototype, and bind it using `Function.prototype.apply.bind();`:

```
Array.prototype.len = function () { return this.length; };
var len = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Array.prototype.len);
len([1,2,3]); // 3
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't allow for the flexibility of a pure `len()` function. Doing `len.call(arr)` isn't an option for me because I shouldn't need to use `call()`. I should be able to define call beforehand so that I just need the function call `len`. Also, the last example wouldn't work because that doesn't take into account other iterable objects like `arguments` and `strings` that this should be able to work on.

Comment: I realized I missed that and added an edit to the bottom - did I get it right this time?

Comment: Very cool. Thank you very much. Could you link me to any articles relating to `Function.prototype.apply` that have helped you? I'm still very shaky on understanding how this works. For some reason, `Array.prototype.slice.call(str)`, `String.prototype` and other built in prototype concepts make sense to me. For some reason, `Function.prototype` concepts trip me up.

Comment: I'd recommend [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes). If you like that book, I'd highly recommend the entire series. It's pretty short. Maybe [this article too](https://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/). You're on the right track with MDN though, and if you keep reading and trying it'll click.